# How to combine two array?

Tags: php, arrays

My array is like this :

```
$data1 = array(
        "total_transaction" => 100,
        "month"             => 'May'
);

$data2 = array(
        "total_transaction" => 200,
        "month"             => 'June'
);
```

I want to combine 2 array above like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total_transaction] => 100
            [month] => 'May'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total_transaction] => 200
            [month] => 'June'
        )
)
```

I try using array_merge, array_combine etc.

```
$data = array_merge($data1, $data2);
$data = array_combine($data1, $data2);
```

But it's not working

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Why is it not working? What the output of those calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a new array:

```
$newArray = [$data1, $data2];
```

Or, if you prefer the `array()` syntax:

```
$newArray = array($data1, $data2);
```